# JavaScript get attribution from select

Tags: javascript

Consider:

```
<select id="test">
   <option attribut="1">test 1</option>
   <option attribut="2">test 2</option>
   <option attribut="3">test 3</option>
   <option attribut="4">test 4</option>
   <option attribut="5">test 5</option>
</select>
```

I want to get the selected item's attribute. Is there any simple way to do it? The native JavaScript is fine.

Comment: As a footnote, if you do want to define your own attributes, please prefix them with `data-` to make them HTML5 forward compatible.

Comment: so I can define my own attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rename 'attribut' to 'value' in your HTML. You can however define you own attributes and read them too (if validation is of no concern, and for [HTML5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5) you can prefix your custom attribute with 'data-').  Looks like:

```
<select id="test">
   <option value="1" data-attrib="five">test 1</option>
   <option value="2" data-attrib="four">test 2</option>
   <option value="3" data-attrib="three">test 3</option>
   <option value="4" data-attrib="two">test 4</option>
   <option value="5" data-attrib="one">test 5</option>
</select>
​
```

Now for this select you can get the option values and 'attrib' values with something like:

```
function getOpts(){
  var mySelect = document.getElementById('test')
      , opts = mySelect.options
      , results = ''
      , i=0
      , len = opts.length;
  while (i<len){
        results += opts[i].getAttribute('data-attrib')+'-'+
                   (opts[i].selected 
                      ? 'selected value: '+opts[i].value 
                      : opts[i].value)+'\n';
        i++;
  }
  return '\n'+results;
}
```

​(If you also seek the text value of the option, you can append `opts[i].firstChild.nodeValue` to the results variable.)

Answer (score 4):

There's no `attribut` attribute defined on the `option` tag. This is not standard HTML. A more standard way is to use the `value` attribute:

```
<select id="test">
   <option value="1">test 1</option>
   <option value="2">test 2</option>
   <option value="3">test 3</option>
   <option value="4">test 4</option>
   <option value="5">test 5</option>
</select>
```

which allows you to do this:

```
var value = document.getElementById('test').value;
alert(value); // shows the selected value
```

Comment: can I add a custom attribution to store the information?I know there is already value, but I need another one.

Comment: What other information do you want to store than the value? Usually the value is an identifier which allows you to retrieve any other related information in your data store.

Comment: For example,for each option, there are three different fields need be stored. I can put one in the text, another one in value. Can I define a custom attribution to store my third one?

Comment: @yongwei-xing: See my answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941578/javascript-get-attribution-from-select/2941756#2941756) for the use of custom attributes. Maybe it helps?

Answer (score 0):

```
d = document.getElementById("test");
// This will get the first attribute of the first option
// Change the indices accordingly to get the others
myattr = d[0].attributes[0].value;
```

Of course, this is not standard HTML

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @darin. The following code gives you the value of the option on changing event.

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
   function getValue(){
    val = document.getElementById("test").value;
    alert(""+val)       
   }
    </script>

<select id="test"  name="selectName" size="1" onChange="getValue();">
   <option value="1">test 1</option>
   <option value="2">test 2</option>
   <option  value="3">test 3</option>
   <option value="4">test 4</option>
   <option value="5">test 5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You event handler passes a parameter to the handler which a) doesn't have a parameter definition and b) never uses the passed value.

Comment: @nikc :- Sorry i Edit it sorry again.